# Ruby inject method

Tags: ruby

I'm doing some ruby exercises. In one of the solutions of my exercise, I found this code.

```
def make_change(amount)
  { H:50, Q:25, D:10, N:5, P:1 }.inject({}) do |res, (k,v)| 
    change, amount = amount.divmod(v)
    res[k] = change unless change==0
    res
  end
end
```

This method takes an amount as parameter and associates coins to equal it. For example:

```
make_change(75) 
#=> {H:1, Q:1}    

(50 + 25 = 75)
```

But I don't understand where the `change` variable come from. How is the variable filled?

Comment: `change, amount = amount.divmod(v)`

Comment: It's one of the values returned from [`Numeric#divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) in this line:  `change, amount = amount.divmod(v)`

Comment: It gets its value from multi-assignment. `divmod()` returns a 2 element array, and those 2 are expanded and assigned to `change, amount`

Answer (score 1):

> But i doesnt understand where does the "change" variable come from, how the variable is filled ?

`change` is defined and initialized in the first line of the block:

```
change, amount = amount.divmod(v)
```